# How to restrict an element value being lower than another in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, schema, restriction

I needed to have a restriction on an element. Given two elements like:

```
<xs:element name="lowerValue" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
     <xs:element name="higgerValue" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> 
          <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:minLength value= lowerValue />
               </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

In higgerValue needed to restrict the value to be no lower than lowerValue.

It is possible? How do I can do set the minimun value accepted the value of another element?

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.1 you can define an assertion. The assertion goes on the containing element (let's say `container` is the parent of both `lowerValue` and `higherValue`). Then on the definition of element `container`, you can write `<xs:assert test="higherValue gt lowerValue"/>`.

Cross-element constraints aren't possible in XSD 1.0.

Comment: I thought so. Assertion is not possible in my case. Thank you any!